# Is there a way to login to my laptop using ssh after boot?

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to login to my laptop after boot using ssh key instead of password? I know this is possible if I want to connect remotely.

Comment: Do you want to log into the desktop?

Comment: Is your home folder encrypted?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes.

Comment: @muru, no it's not encrypted.